# How to prove $f_+$, $f_-$, $|f|$ are continous almost everywhere (equivalently, Riemann integrable)?

Tags: measure-theory

How to prove $f_+$, $f_-$, $|f|$ are continous almost everywhere (equivalently, Riemann integrable) given $f$ is continous almost everywhere (equivalently, Riemann integrable)?

※Sorry, i forgot to include my attempt.
Let $A$ = {$x$ : $f(x)$ is continuous at $x$} and $B$ = {$x$ : $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x$}. Then $A \cup B$ is a whole set, denoted by X.
Choose any $x$ in $A$. Then, for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $y\in X$ for which $|x-y|<\delta$.
Then i have for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $||f(x)|-|f(y)||\leq|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $y\in X$ for which $|x-y|<\delta$. And this implies that $x\in$ {$x$: $|f(x)|$ is continuous at $x$} = $A'$. Hence $A\subset A'$ and $(A')^\complement \subset A^\complement = B$. Thus the set of all discontinuous points of $|f(x)|$ is a null set. Therefore $|f(x)|$ is continuous a.e.

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For |f(x)| the answer is very simple! ||f(x)|-|f(y)||$\leqslant$ |f(x)-f(y)| so if f is continuous at y, which belongs to a set of full measure, then for each ε>0 there exists a δ such that |x-y|<δ implies |f(x)-f(y)| But then also ||f(x)|-|f(y)||<ε and we are done! How do you define f+ , f-?

Comment: f+ , f- can be defined by (f+|f|)/2 and (|f|-f)/2 and sum of functions which are continuous a.e. is also continuous a.e.